# Can I specify an AWS DynamoDB policy based on Cognito ID?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

Can I apply a policy to an AWS DynamoDB table but restrict it based on the Cognito ID of the user accessing it?

E.g. A Customer table has a primary hash key equal to the Cognito ID. When anyone but the user sharing the same ID tries to get the item they will receive an unauthorised exception.

(Non DynanoDB policies are probably also valid.)

Comment: did you define user id as hash and another attribute as range or only hash key? I am trying the solution below with has+range but it doesnt work for me unfortunately. I am keep getting "AccessDeniedException". Also what is the name of hashy key. I called it "UserId". not sure if exact name is important or not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this using the same techniques as those for [using an ID Provider](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxERCU1UMRFNPB/DynamoDB-on-Mobile-Part-5-Fine-Grained-Access-Control). You should [use the Cognito identifier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html#iampolicy-example-wif-cognito) as the key in the policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:Query"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:dynamodb:REGION:123456789012:table/UserData"],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]}
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: So what if I want a teacher/supervisor to be able to see all employee/student records? The teacher's identity wouldn't match those of their students', right?

Comment: @AlleyOOP Did you find an answer to this?