# How to store user information with DynamoDB and Cognito using Facebook authentication with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

Is it appropriate to combine `Cognito` identity management with `Dynamo DB`?

I would like to authenticate *users* with **Facebook**, which I can do with `Cognito` and then store user related data in a `DynamoDB` table.

What information would I use from `Cognito` as a *primary key* for my table to guarantee unicity? Or should I simply use the *facebookId* that I can get with the *graph API?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the cognito identity ID as the hash key for your DynamoDB table, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867193/can-i-specify-an-aws-dynamodb-policy-based-on-cognito-id) for an example IAM policy.

Comment: So, more generally, I have to have the hash key as the user in all cases I want to secure my data like this? Could I add it as another field of the table?

Comment: @TiborUdvari If you want to restrict access to the whole item then you must use an indexed attribute. You can also restrict access to columns of the table, but it sounded more like you were trying to partition the table by user, this would mean using the identity ID. You can refer to the [DynamoDB docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html) for more examples of fine-grained access control.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have a rather complex Use Case ... Now with the docs I see how it's possible to implement.