# AWS DynamoDB user authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

currently I am working with AWS DynamoDB and I struggle with **user authorization and restricting access** to specific items inside of a DynamoDB Table.
I have already read the documentation and came across multiple blog posts, but unfortunately I haven't found my use case yet.

**Some background information:**

Each user of the web app belongs to a company and each company has multiple orders. These orders are inside of the DynamoDB table "Orders". What I want to achieve is that the users can only read order items from the company they belong to.

**My Approach**

My idea was to create the "Orders" table with a partition key of "companyId" and a sort key of "orderId". During my research I figured out that I can restrict the access through IAM Policy roles, but I couldn't find a way to access the companyId of the user inside of the policy role. Users are authenticating through AWS Cognito.

**My Question**

How can I restrict the user access specific items inside of a DynamoDB? Taking into account the each user belongs to a company and should only see orders of this company.

Looking forward to some help!

Comment: Are you asking if dynamodb can limit access to a partition of data based on the current user's identity, like Row-Level Security  in other database system, or are how to restrict access through code.

Comment: Hi @RossBush, yes correct, I want to setup something like Row-Level Security in other data base systems. E.g. a user that belongs to company A can only read order from DynamoDB Table "Orders" which have an attribute companyId: "company A".

Answer (score 2):

AWS has published [Isolating SaaS Tenants with Dynamically Generated IAM Policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/isolating-saas-tenants-with-dynamically-generated-iam-policies/) blog on their website. This blog explains exactly the thing that you want to achieve.

In short, I can explain:

1. Use **CustomerId** as **PartitionKey**
2. Create an IAM policy with access on **Orders** table like below

   ```
   1 {
   2  "Version": "2012-10-17",
   3  "Statement": [
   4    {
   5      "Action": [
   6        "dynamodb:GetItem",
   7        "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
   8        "dynamodb:Query",
   9        "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
   10      ],
   11      "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Orders",
   12      "Effect": "Allow"
   13    }
   14  ]
   15 }
   ```
3. Create a template for [Session Policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/create-fine-grained-session-permissions-using-iam-managed-policies/) where you will replace CustomerId with incoming request's customerId on runtime.

   ```
   1  {
   2    "Effect": "Allow",
   3    "Action": [
   4         "dynamodb:*"
   5    ],
   6    "Resource": [
   7         "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/{{table}}"
   8    ],
   9    "Condition": {
   10        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
   11            "dynamodb: LeadingKeys": [ "{{customerId}}" ]
   12        }
   13    }
   14 }
   ```
4. Now, invoke **STS (Security Token Service)** with above IAM & Session policy to get **temporary credentials** that has access limited to a single tenant/customer data.

   Below is the pseudo code, you can use your programming language's SDK to write below code.

   ```
   AssumeRoleResponse response = sts.assumeRole (ar -> ar
        .webIdentityToken(openIdToken)
        .policy(scopedPolicy)
        .roleArn(role));
   Credentials tenantCredentials = response.credentials();
   DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient = DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .credentialsProvider(tenantCredentials)
        .build();
   ```
5. Finally, create `DynamoDBClient` object using these temporary credentials and  use it. This object of `DynamoDBClient` will have access to only current user's customer data.

Hope this should help!

Answer (score 1):

Using custom attributes, you can create a backend layer that will check these parameters, query DynamoDB with the specified attribute, and return them - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html

The second option is to set up role for each company - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html#using-rules-to-assign-roles-to-users

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Regarding your first option: Do you have some more information! This is exactly where I struggle. Your approach, that each user will get a custom attribute, in my case companyId, right? Do you mean that I use this attribute inside of IAM User Policy?

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888309/13126651

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes I found this post, but it doesn't handle the issue that a user belongs to a group in our case a company and we have to checke for the company instead of the user id!

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel I think I understood your approach for option 1. This would mean that I have to create a user pool for each company with a custom attribute e.g. "companyId", right?