# Restrict Cognito User to only access their DynamoDB data

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a simple to-do application where users can create to-do lists.

I have an API gateway that sits in front of a lambda function thats used for CRUD operations to a DynamoDB table (create list, create item, get items, etc).

I've setup an Authorizer on the API gateway so that only logged in Cognito users can call my APIs. However, Users can perform CRUD operations ANY list, not just their own lists.

How do I restrict access to CRUD operations for only their lists?

User -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB

Comment: You can use STS to generate temporary credentials that will have access on only specific Partition Key in DynamoDB. Refer this, you will get some idea - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73795880/1273882

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the customer identifier as the DynamoDB partition key then you can use [fine grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "AllowAccessToOnlyItemsMatchingUserID",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"dynamodb:GetItem",
"dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
"dynamodb:Query",
"dynamodb:PutItem",
"dynamodb:UpdateItem",
"dynamodb:DeleteItem",
"dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/GameScores"
],
"Condition": {
"ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
"dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
    "${www.amazon.com:user_id}"
],
"dynamodb:Attributes": [
    "UserId",
    "GameTitle",
    "Wins",
    "Losses",
    "TopScore",
    "TopScoreDateTime"
]
},
"StringEqualsIfExists": {
"dynamodb:Select": "SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES"
}
}
}
]
}
```

You use the IAM Condition element to implement a fine-grained access control policy. By adding a Condition element to a permissions policy, you can allow or deny access to items and attributes in DynamoDB tables and indexes, based upon your particular business requirements.

[This blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/isolating-saas-tenants-with-dynamically-generated-iam-policies/) takes you through the more finer details to achieve your needs.

Comment: my ddb table looks like: listId (PK), listName, userId. I'm unable to user userId since ddb complains that it must be unique and users can have multiple lists.

I tried following this blog (below), which had me create an Federate/Identity Pool, and applies a role with a LeadingKeys conditional: {cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} to my User Pool users but doing this does not restrict access. My Lambda execution role has full DDB access which is probably why, and changing it to the same role with the conditional results in "no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:GetItem action" error.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/

Comment: The leading key must be an exact match on the partition key. So your Cognito sub must match your partition key exactly, if it doesn't it won't work. Use a sort key for uniqueness of you need to.